# Get all rows of a window in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a use case where we need to find patterns in data within a window. We are experimenting with Structured Streaming. We have a continues stream of events and are looking for patterns like event A (device disconnect) is followed by event B (device reconnect) within 10 seconds. or event A (disconnect) is not followed by event B (reconnect) within 10 seconds.

I was thinking of using a window function grouping dataset into 10 seconds window buckets and checking for the pattern every time the window values are updated. It looks like the window function is really used as a groupBy in structured streaming which forces me to use aggregate functions to get high level agg on column values.

I am wondering if there is a way to loop through all values of the column when using window function in structured streaming.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that without grouping? I have a similar use case where I don't want to perform high level aggregation but get the events on a windows and perform CEP like you mentioned above.

Comment: @BiplobBishwas nope. I ended up using dstream instead and grouped by key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's exactly what we are thinking of doing now. If that doesn't work the way we expect we might soon move to Flink CEP. Anyway thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using mapGroupsWithState (structured streaming) or mapWithState (DStreams), it sounds like it could work well for your case.

You can keep arbitrary state for any key and update the state everytime an update comes. You can also set a timeout for each key after which its state will get removed. For your use case, you could store the initial state for event A as the timestamp of when A arrived, and when event B comes you can check if the timestamp is within 10s of A. If it is, generate an event.

You might also be able to use timeouts for this, e.g. set the initial state when A comes, set the timeout to 10s, and if A is still around when B comes then generate an event.

[Good blog post](http://asyncified.io/2017/07/30/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-spark-structured-streaming/) on the differences b/w mapGroupsWithState and mapWithState